# how does mysql allocate the key length of a primary key or foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, sql-tuning

I created a table with 2 different charset type: utf8, and latin1.

1)

```
CREATE TABLE `aaa` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

2)

```
CREATE TABLE `aaa` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then I insert value into several rows. 
When using 'explain' to select both tables, I got different key_len:

1)

```
mysql> explain select count(*) from aaa where name = "haha";
```

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | row                               s | Extra                    |

|  1 | SIMPLE      | aaa   | ref  | name          | name | 258     | const |                                   2 | Using where; Using index |

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

2)

```
mysql> explain select count(*) from aaa where name = "haha";
```

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | row                               s | Extra                    |

|  1 | SIMPLE      | aaa   | ref  | name          | name | 768     | const |                                   2 | Using where; Using index |

1 row in set (0.01 sec)

I don't know how does the system allocate the key_len for the similar tables which were defined using different charset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As utf8 is a multi-byte character set, MySQL needs to reserve three bytes for each character:

```
utf8, a UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set using one to three bytes per character.
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode.html

Besides that, there seems to be three bytes of overhead.